# Cocos2d vs SpriteKit

Tags: spritekit, ios, objective-c, разработка-игр, cocos2d

Есть желание сделать первый совсем маленький игровой 2д проект только для `iOS`. На фоне этого стало интересно попробовать `SpriteKit`. Судя по документации, по своему подходу и реализации он довольно похож на `Cocos2d for iPhone`. Возможно ли что он будет показывать более высокие результаты по производительности и эффективности чем `Cocos2d`? Сравнивая эти два фреймворка, какие преимущества и недостатки у них могут быть по отношению друг к другу?

Comment: Лучше беспокойтесь о производительности и эффективности разработчика (т.е. как легко и быстро чего-то добиться), а не о производительности и эффективности движков.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мне кажется, если есть время и возможность, лучше бери сразу новый спрайт-кит, по возможностям он очень похож на кокос (я мельком посмотрел документацию, примеры кода очень похожи), возможно даже лучше, но ios точно чаще обновляется и будут появляться новые фичи и т.д. Кстати, не факт что кокос будет сразу поддерживать ios 7.
А производительность всегда можно проверить, сделать 2 одинаковые сцены в кокосе и в спрайт-кит и добавляя к примеру - кучу спрайтов смотреть как меняется фпс. Возможно уже есть сравнение этих фреймворков, надо поискать...

Comment: Спасибо за комментарий! По сути и кокос и спрайткит работают одинаково, поэтому и вопрос есть ли смысл в спрайтките (кокос как минимум уже давно и довольно стабильно работает). Вероятно это из-за того что Xcode 5 пока в бете, но в симуляторе у меня при 10 спрайтах в сцене уже 10фпс.